# How to make multiple time zones always visible in Windows taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-10, timezones, time

On my Mac, I use [Clocker](https://abhishekbanthia.com/clocker/) to show various time zones, always visible on my screen like this:
[image: multiple clocks]

How can I do something similar on Windows 10?

P.S. I am *not* satisfied with the built-in Windows feature shown below because 1) it requires me clicking to see the clocks, 2) I'd prefer to add clocks by city so that I don't need to worry about whether daylight saving is in effect, and 3) it only allows 2 additional clocks.

[image: built-in Windows feature]

Answer (score 2):

There are few options available,
World Clock widget: This built-in widget is analog-only and quite basic, but it gets the job done.

https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9nrkvtwgjktk?hl=en-US&gl=US

Widgetsmith: This popular widget-builder utility has a World Clock feature that shows the time in multiple locations in digital format. It's also immensely customizable.

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/widgetsmith/id1523682319

World Clock Time Widget: This one is great for time-zone conversion. It also has a visual timeline of each location, so you'll know if it's day, night, or the next day, in a given location

https://apps.apple.com/us/app/world-clock-time-widget/id912698955

Also , There is a browser plugin “ FoxClocks ”that can be used to display multiple time zones

[https://foxclocks.org/#:~:text=FoxClocks%20is%20an%20extension%20for,to%20create%20and%20very%20flexible](https://foxclocks.org/#:%7E:text=FoxClocks%20is%20an%20extension%20for,to%20create%20and%20very%20flexible).

Comment: Welcome Ragini! Thank you for contributing an answer.  Your answer can be improved if you include links to the software you recommended.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any links to screenshots? I've been searching for the terms you mentioned, but I haven't found any indication that they'd help me replace the current clock in the Windows taskbar with some number of digital clocks with various time zones labeled. Thanks.